# Reload tableview in iOS6 does not work properly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6

I have developed a simple app where I have to sort a tableview according to the option the user picks in another viewcontroller. So far so good because with iOS 7 it is working perfect, however the same code running on iOS6 isn't. As the app is pretty simple I'd like to keep compatible also with the iOS6, so for this after the sort, I am using the method tableview.reload, but I am not having success with iOS 6. Is there a way to workaround this issue and keep compatible for both platforms??

Comment: Post the code of the non-compatible method.

Comment: after reloading the content in the textfield, I do:
[self.tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to call is:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

I don't know what tableView.reload is, but don't call a void returning method with dot notation. I don't know if that even works, but it's awful.

Do this for me:

Place this at the top of the file under the #imports:

```
static NSString *const CellIdentifier = @"ThisIsAUniqueID";
```

When initialising/configuring the tableView do this:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

In the `cellForRow:` method do this:

```
/**
 *  Asks the data source for a cell to insert in a particular location of the table view.
 *
 *  @param  tableView                   A table-view object requesting the cell.
 *  @param  indexPath                   An index path locating a row in tableView.
 *
 *  @return An object inheriting from UITableViewCell that the table view can use for the specified row.
 */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = [tableView viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = sortedArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, as I didn't have the code in hand I didn't pay attention what I wrote at that time.
But I am following what you have mentioned like this:
[self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: reloadData does work with iOS6. Something else is the cause of your incompatibility, I'm assuming cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: It might be ... let me share the code of this method:
<code>
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];
UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
[label1 setText:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
</code>

Comment: Its pretty interesting because the same code works on iOS7 but not on iOS6, and before upgrading to Xcode5 it was working fine.

Comment: @aburb I have same story here , what was the solution ?

Comment: hi @Roma-MT, I have reviewed my implementation according to the posts quoted above, it worked well. Thank you all